# Getting Null value when there is no null in Database table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web

So what i am doing is that i am taking the response from a api endpoint, saving it to my DB table and then displaying the table contents.

I have gone through possible reasons as to why one can get a null value, as explained here http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-515.aspx, and none of those reasons apply in this case.

For this particular table, i am getting a exception error,

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception
>   for details.

Here is the exception message i get:

> An error has occurred.
>    Cannot insert the value NULL into column
>   'FrameSizeID', table 'diafirearmserver.dbo.Reference_Frame_Sizes';
>   column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been
>   terminated. 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.b__167_0(Task`1
>   result) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() --- End of stack trace from
>   previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.d__0.MoveNext()

**My Questions is:** Why am i getting a null value being passed, when the table (Screenshot below) has no null values in it? What am i overlooking?

[image: Here is a screenshot of the table that feeds the 'External api endpoint']
Here is my data model:

```
namespace FirearmsAPI.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Reference_Frame_Sizes
    {
        public int FrameSizeID { get; set; }
        public string FrameSize { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
public class Reference_Frame_SizesController : ApiController
{
    private DataEntities db = new DataEntities();
    static string _address = "http://localhost:57454/api/Reference_Frame_Sizes?format=json";
    private List<Reference_Frame_Sizes> result;

    // GET: api/Reference_Frame_Sizes
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves Firearm Frame size data from external api endpoint, saves data to DB and returns Data
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Reference_Frame_Sizes>> GetReference_Frame_Sizes()
    {
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE Reference_Frame_Sizes"); //Truncates internal table

        List<Reference_Frame_Sizes> resultset = await GetResponse();
        foreach (Reference_Frame_Sizes manu in resultset)
        {
            db.Reference_Frame_Sizes.Add(manu);
        }
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return db.Reference_Frame_Sizes;
    }

    private async Task<List<Reference_Frame_Sizes>> GetResponse()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_address);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Reference_Frame_Sizes>>();
        return result;
    }

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool Reference_Frame_SizesExists(int id)
    {
        return db.Reference_Frame_Sizes.Count(e => e.FrameSizeID == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the results that are being returned in the GetResponse method.

Comment: It might be because you never mapped `FrameSizeID` in your EF mappings. In that case EF will ignore those values on insert and it will default to the default value of `NULL` in the DB unless you have a default constraint setup AND are using Sql Server. This is a guess because you did not supply the EF mapping code for `Reference_Frame_Sizes` but a likely one considering its an `int` property so if it were mapped but no value was assigned then the value of `0` would always be used and you would get a different error entirely.

Comment: @Igor I checked the FrameSizeID mapping, and its mapped correctly.

Comment: Are you using/mapping stored procs for the inserts with EF? Either way if you want further help you will have to show your model mapping code as well as the rest of the partial class `Reference_Frame_Sizes`. Else you will have to figure it out on your own as there is not enough to go on.

Comment: @Igor My apologies, how do i view the EF to model mapping code?. I only know how to view the Table mapping, while viewing the edmx file.

Comment: @saturobi360 - take a screenshot of the properties in the EDMX designer for `FrameSizeID` and post that. My guess is its either mapped to the wrong column name OR you have something set on it like `identity` or `computed` that would make EF try to not provide a value on `INSERT`.

Comment: @Igor http://i693.photobucket.com/albums/vv293/saturobi360/FrameSize%20Property_zpsfuogh5xw.jpg

Comment: @saturobi360 - once you apply your fix and it works please remember to mark the answer with the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the EF mapping. The property `FrameSizeID` has the property `StoreGeneratedPattern` set to `identity` which means that EF will never try to provide a value at insert time. You need to remove that so that EF knows you will provide a value when you create a new record in the database. As EF does not provide a value and the value cannot be null this is generating the exception you are experiencing.

#### Solution Recap

Set the value of `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `None` for property `FrameSizeID`.

[Supporting Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.storegeneratedpattern(v=vs.110).aspx)

#### Note

This is based on the latest comment that provided the following screen shot:

[image: EF Properties for FrameSizeID]

Comment: Thanks so much @Igor, you where very patient in guiding me through working out the issue. Many thanks from me.

Comment: although this is obviously the solution, it should be mentioned the mapping is not false by default. it just doesn't match the database schema. for that reason, setting the column to IDENTITY would solve this issue as well.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro - the OP is getting the data from an external web service including the value for property/column `FrameSizeID` so in this situation an Identity column would not work because the OP wants to explicitly set the value of the column and not have a sequential database generated value.

Answer (score 2):

You're not getting that error, because you're reading null values **from** the database, you're getting it because you're trying to insert null values **into** the database.

[Use the debugger](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn) to evaluate the result of the `GetResponse()` method. odds are that one of the `FrameSizeID` properties is null.

Comment: I thought that as well but his model has an `int` type for `FrameSizeID` and `FrameSizeID` is listed in the Exception message as the column with the `NULL` value. I assumed that the column name and property name were the same. As its an `int` type you could never pass in `NULL` unless you did so with an stored proc or something with ADO.NET. I was thinking this would make sense if the mapping was not correct as then the int value would never be passed. `... Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'FrameSizeID'`

Comment: GetResponse returns 8 values, as it should.
Here is a screenshot:
http://i693.photobucket.com/albums/vv293/saturobi360/Debugger_GetResponse_zpsqplanhi1.jpg

Comment: @saturobi360 - that is not interesting, what is of interest is the values in each object. If none of the mapped properties in your returned collection have a `null` value where there should not be one then the only other option as to why it is failing is incorrect EF mapping of your model to your database.

Comment: Here is another screenshot showing that GetResponse() returns values:
http://i693.photobucket.com/albums/vv293/saturobi360/Debugger_GetResponse2_zpsk4d24gfy.png

None of the returned objects in the collection has a null value in it.

Comment: @saturobi360 - then its your EF to model mapping. Supply that code if you want further help, I also commented this on your post.

Comment: @Igor. My apologies, how do i view the EF to model mapping code?.
 I only know how to view the Table mapping, while viewing the edmx file.